# Set minimum characters in WooCommerce product search widget

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I'm using WooCommerce product search widget and add `minlength="17"` fragment in this code:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
   <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( 'Search for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
   <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search Products&hellip;', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" minlength="17" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
   <input type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```

And it works very nice in Chrome. It shows a message:

> "Please lengthen this text to 17 characters or more(You are currently
>   use * characters)".

This is what I need, but it doesn't in **Firefox** and **IE**.
When I put 3,4 or less then 17 characters in search field, It starts search.

What to do? How to make it working in all browsers?!

Comment: try something like this, `<input pattern=".{17,}"   required title="17 characters minimum">`

Comment: minlength is not supported in all browsers currently ..http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/18-minlength.html?text=1234567890&text2=

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to implement <input pattern=".{17,}" required title="17 characters minimum"> in my code. Anyway, it will nor work in all browser I think.

Comment: `pattern=".{17,}" required title="17 characters minimum"` this is what you need.

Comment: And where exactly can I add this fragment in code above??

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't search in woocommerce product area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out.

```html
<form action="">

<input minlength="17" >
<input pattern=".{17,}"   required title="17 characters minimum">
<input pattern=".{5,10}" required title="5 to 10 characters">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5d1Lfj2r/)

Comment: did you check the demo? check this in firefox, ie.. https://fiddle.jshell.net/5d1Lfj2r/show/light/

Comment: Of course I did. This last link even doesn't show any fields to put the text in FF and IE. It works in Chrome only.

Comment: what version are your browsers?

Comment: I update FF and now it works in FF as well in Chrome. But not in IE 9. I use this code now https://jsfiddle.net/merkucio1/ufcffbjh/8/ strange but it works in FF and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with javascript code

```
<input onblur="checkLength(this)" id="groupidtext" type="text" style="width: 100px;" minlength="6" />
<!-- or use event onkeyup instead if you want to check every character strike-->


function checkLength(el) {
  if (el.value.length <= 6) {
    alert("length must be atleast 6 characters")
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please more clear where can I add this code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this snippet, i hope this code will help

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
 
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, minimum length 17: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 17
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Internet Explorer and mobile/responsive version

Comment: @Merkucio i am pasting a jquery code snippet for validation